# Why is my code not working (java netbeans)?

Tags: java, math, netbeans, formula

i want the code to calculate the netpay formula.
This is the code I used, it has no errors in the program but when I run it, it just says build success and doesn't calculate.

```
package com.mycompany.netpay;

public class NetPay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
    double h = 40;
    double i = 2.00;
    double t = 0.22;
    double w = 5.00;
    double result = (h * w - i) - t * (h * w - i);
}
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to print the result. Use `System.out.println()`. I made that error over and over when I was new to programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you need your code within the method, not out of it. Try this :)

```
package com.mycompany.netpay;

public class NetPay {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double h = 40;
        double i = 2.00;
        double t = 0.22;
        double w = 5.00;
        double result = (h * w - i) - t * (h * w - i);
        // System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

You're not logging this out to the console or system however, so you may still not see a result. Search "How to print to system in Java" for more information.